# Using Registration Free COM in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba, regfreecom

I have been struggling to use Registration Free COM to make .NET calls from Excel 2010. Essentially I wanted to be able to call some .NET API functions in an Excel macro. I created a wrapper API in .NET, and exposed that wrapper as a COM-callable library. The code for that is as follows:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports NXOpen
Imports NXOpen.UF
Imports NXOpen.Assemblies

Namespace ExcelNXInterface

<Guid("bbe0089d-a732-4743-922b-180b30006fa4"), _
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
Public Interface _ExcelNXInterface
    <DispId(1)> Sub HighlightCompTag(ByRef tag As Long)
    <DispId(2)> Sub Echo(ByVal output As String)
End Interface

<ComVisible(True)>
<Guid("1376DE24-CC2D-46cb-8BF0-887A9CAF3014"), _
 ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), _
 ProgId("ExcelNXInterface.ExcelNXInterface")> Public Class ExcelNXInterface
    Implements _ExcelNXInterface

    Public _ExcelNXInterface

    Dim theSession As Session = Session.GetSession()
    Dim ufs As UFSession = UFSession.GetUFSession()

    Public Sub HighlightCompTag(ByRef tag As Long) Implements _ExcelNXInterface.HighlightCompTag

        Try
            ufs.Disp.SetHighlight(tag, 1)
            Echo("Component(s) Highlighted...")
        Catch e As NXException
            Echo("NX Exception is: {0} " + e.Message)
        Catch e As Exception
            Echo("Exception is: {0} " & e.Message)
            Echo("DONE!" & vbLf)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Sub Echo(ByVal output As String) Implements _ExcelNXInterface.Echo

        theSession.ListingWindow.Open()
        theSession.ListingWindow.WriteLine(output)
        theSession.LogFile.WriteLine(output)

    End Sub

End Class

End Namespace
```

The manifest to use Registration Free COM is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly 
  manifestVersion="1.0" 
  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" 
  xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
  xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <assemblyIdentity
    type="win32"
    version="1.0.0.0" 
    name="ExcelNXInterface"/>

  <clrClass
      clsid="{bbe0089d-a732-4743-922b-180b30006fa4}"
      progid="ExcelNXInterface.ExcelNXInterface"
      threadingModel="Both"
      name="ExcelNXInterface.ExcelNXInterface">
  </clrClass>

  <file name = "ExcelNXInterface.dll"></file>   
</asmv1:assembly>
```

To call the wrapped .NET functions in Excel I used the following VBA code:

```
Sub ExNX()
    Dim actCtx As Object
    Set actCtx = CreateObject("Microsoft.Windows.ActCtx")
    actCtx.Manifest = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ExcelNXInterface.dll.manifest"

    Dim myNX As Object
    Set myNX = actCtx.CreateObject("ExcelNXInterface.ExcelNXInterface")

End Sub
```

However, the problem is that when the last line of code is called I get a Run time error 2147024894 (80070002) Method 'CreatObject' of object IActCtx' failed. I honestly don't know what it is that I am doing wrong, or even if this is possible. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

It should be noted that the DLL, manifest and the workbook are all in the same directory. Also it should be noted that VSTO, executable files and/or installations are not options for me. That is why I am trying to stick to using Excel.

Comment: Error code 0x80070002 is a very plain "file not found" error code.  Possibly generated by a FileNotFoundException in your C# code.  The CLR is never going to look in a directory where a workbook is stored.  Your DLL and any dependencies needs to be copied into the Excel install directory or deployed into the GAC.

Comment: You might also try embedding the manifest into the DLL, and assign the full path to the DLL to `actCtx.Manifest` but I haven't tried that with a .Net DLL.  Perhaps for interop those always have to be GACced if they aren't in the EXE's folder.

Comment: It just so happens  that I don't have access to either Program Files or the GAC. Also, I tried embedding the manifest file and that didn't work either. actCtx.Manifest couldn't find the manifest file when I pointed to the dll file. Does this mean I am out of luck?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your project, you could try this approach, also avoiding the need for com registration: https://gitlab.com/jbjurstam/VbaDll/